# Selecting cells surrounding a point with multiple start points

Tags: sql, cartesian-coordinates

I am trying to search a two dimensional grid where each cell is represented by a row in the table mapdata as follows;

```
x-loc
y-loc
attrib1
attrib2
...
attribN
```

I have seperate indices over x-loc and y-loc as well as seperate indices over each of the attrib values that I'm interested in. To select a cell, I need to examine some of the attributes in the cells surrounding the start point I'm interested in.

I can do this when I know the starting point (assuming the start point is 10,10 with a query like;

```
select * from mapdata 
where x-loc in (10-2, 10-1, 10+1,10+2) 
    and y-loc in (10-2,10-1,10+1,10+2) 
    and attrib3=<some value> 
    and attrib4 in (<value1>, <value2>)
```

that will give me a list of the cells surrounding my start point of 10,10 that have the attributes I'm interested in.

However I now need to extend this so that I have multiple possible start points also selected by a query. For example I get my potential start points with

```
select x-loc, y-loc, sum(attrib5) from mapdata 
where attrib1 = <value> 
and attrib2 in (<value>,,value>
```

and I've currently got this implemented in java using JDBC that executes the second query to select possible start points and for each row returned I execute the first query. This is very, very slow.

I've been trying to find ways of forcing the results of a sub-query into the IN clause of my first query or a BETWEEN clause such that for the list of potential start points I get returned only the x-loc and y.loc of those starting points whose surrounding cells match the criteria specified.

Firstly, is what I'm trying to do actually possible? and if so, could someone point me in the right direction please.

Regards

I've now managed to get something working that expresses my intent

```
select c.x,c.y from mapdata a
inner join (select b.x, b.y from mapdata b 
    where b.food = 7 
    and b.terrain_id !=13) c
    on a.x between c.x-2 and c.x +2
    and a.y between c.y-2 and c.y+2
where a.terrain_id in (13,16)
```

but, quite frankly, I could repaint the Sistine Chapel in the time it takes this to run. There has to be a better way.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a set of sample data to play around with?

Comment: How big a sample would you need? The full set is about 8.6M rows :)

Comment: Heh, just enough to be able to run some queries to measure performance, certainly not millions of rows :)

Comment: I've put a sample of 2000 rows on dropbox as a csv file. You can reach it at https://www.dropbox.com/s/2og6za594ritudf/Sample%20Data.csv?dl=0

Comment: cool, I'll take a look at it a bit later.

Comment: If you need a larger sample - let me know :)